# Changing Date Column data format for a Data Column in data table

Tags: c#

How to change Date Column data format for a Data Column in  data table through program. How to achieve this seeking help. I am exporting datatable to CSV. In csv my Date format should be of "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm".

Comment: Can you please show your work as well? Example of input and output as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a CSV file from a `DataTable` and apply a specific format to a date-column you can use `DateTime.ToString` with a [custom format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

In your case you want. `yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm`. But since `/` [will be replaced by your current date separator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dateSeparator) you either have to escape it(`yyyy'/'MM'/'dd hh:mm`) or use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 

IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                  Select(column => column.ColumnName);
sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

var inv = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    IEnumerable<string> fields = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
        .Select(col => col.DataType == typeof(DateTime)
            ? row.Field<DateTime>(col).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm", inv) 
            : row.IsNull(col) ? "" : row[col].ToString());
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
}

File.WriteAllText("filename.csv", sb.ToString());
```

You should choose a safer delimiter than comma.

This presumes that the type of the `DataColumn` is already `DateTime`(what it should be). If it's a string you have to parse it to `DateTime` first to be able to apply the desired format. Therefore use `DateTime.Parse`.